# Safari: using dtrace to investigate iCloud Tab Sync

Tags: icloud, safari

I'm investigating how Safari syncs tabs through iCloud.

To start, I really want to know how Safari is updating its shared list of tabs, which means monitoring it or some background daemon for file creations and modifications. (My hypothesis being: when I open a new tab on my phone, iCloud sends a push to my Mac which updates Safari's "iCloud Tabs" list.)

I'm trying to use `dtrace` to monitor Safari's file opens, with something simple like:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry /execname == "Safari"/ { printf ("%s", copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

but `dtrace` prints out this error:

```
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 160: syscall::open:entry): invalid user access in action #1 at DIF offset 24
```

(This is the same error [as someone asked on Apple's forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7047201))

[Debugging a strange iTunes permissions problem with DTrace](http://adamrosenfield.com/blog/2011/11/27/debugging-a-strange-itunes-permissions-problem-with-dtrace/) had information about a similar issue with iTunes, but I don't quite understand what backflips they performed in `gdb` to get iTunes to be `dtrace`-able.

1. Can someone help me understand [Debugging a strange iTunes permissions problem with DTrace](http://adamrosenfield.com/blog/2011/11/27/debugging-a-strange-itunes-permissions-problem-with-dtrace/): what's the error caused by, and what's the resolution?
2. Do you have any additional knowledge/information about iCloud Tab syncing? What process syncs them? Where are they stored on-disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that contains the iCloud tabs is:

```
~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
```

It's a binary file, so you can use `plutil` to convert a copy to JSON/XML for processing. I expected the syncing to be via `bird` but some light spelunking with `brctl log -w` and other light snooping don't reflect changes I make to the tab database. There are quite a few nice projects on [github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=iCloud%20tab) that parse this file in python, JS as well as a nice menu bar app:

- https://github.com/josh-/CloudyTabs

Knowing where the data persists on disk shows that `syncdefaultsd` is the owning process:

```
sudo fsusage -w | grep com.apple.Safari
```

Sadly, that private framework and daemon are basically undocumented by Apple save for what you can glean from the launchd plist for the service.

Comment:  this is fantastic, thank you! Now I can dive into my Time Machine backup for some lost tabs…

Comment: I also didn't know about the projects which read that file. Cool!